# 504: GATEWAY_TIMEOUT: While hosting on Vercel. Only on a specific api endpoint

Tags: mongodb, express, backend, vercel

I am attempting to deploy my backend on Vercel, and while the root endpoint ("/") is functioning correctly, I am encountering issues when trying to access the "/books" endpoint as it does not seem to be working as expected.

```
import express, { response } from 'express';
import { port, mongoURL } from './config.js';
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import { Book } from './models/bookModel.js';
import booksRoute from './routes/booksRoute.js';
import cors from 'cors';

const app = express();

app.use(express.json());

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req);
    return res.status(234).send("Welcome")
});

app.use(cors());

// Middleware for parsing req body
app.use('/books', booksRoute)

// if connected to db then only start server
mongoose
    .connect(mongoURL)
    .then(() => {
        console.log("connceted to db");
        app.listen(port, () => {
            console.log('listening on port ' + port);
        })
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
    });

export default app;
```

I have checked the code multiple times but can't figure out.